# Простой запрос на SQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть две таблицы статьи и категории. В категориях есть `id`, `cat_name`. В статьях `id`, `id_cat`, `post_name`. Нужно посчитать сколько статей содержит категория и вывести `id`, `cat_name`, `count`

Comment: Попробуйте: `select c.id, c.cat_name, count(a.id) from categories c left join article a on a.id_cat = c.id`

Comment: @MrFylypenko, некорректно выводит результат. Может надо использовать groupby?

Comment: Да, про него забыл: `select c.id, c.cat_name, count(a.id) from categories c left join article a on a.id_cat = c.id group by c.id`